# How can i remove some Injected Script

Tags: javascript, gwt

I am injecting a script in my GWT Application

```
   ScriptInjector.fromUrl("js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js").setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).setCallback(new Callback<Void, Exception>()
        {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void paramT)
            {
                ScriptInjector.fromUrl("js/viewer-2.2.1/WebViewer.min.js").setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).setCallback(new Callback<Void, Exception>()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void paramT)
                    {
                        ScriptInjector.fromString(getCreateInjection()).setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).setRemoveTag(false).inject();
                    }....
```

Now later in the appliation is there a way to remove this script which i injected earlier.

Comment: Why? What is the usecase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, due to how JS works, you can probably do what you are describing and remove the script tag itself, but probably cannot do what you actually mean - the code has been executed, you can't put the toothpaste back in the tube. It it usually possible to remove the script tag, and maybe be possible delete some of the created functions or types that were created, but any code that is already running and interacting with your page is going to stick around until it decided to be done.

Instead, you want to understand the JS script you are using to see if there is a way to ask it to be done, remove any elements it has modified, etc.

--

Both `fromUrl` and `fromString` variants use an `inject()` method, and both methods return a `JavaScriptObject`. That object is the actual `<script>` tag - you can cast it to `Element` and invoke `removeFromParent()` on it, and the script tag will be gone - but the side effects from including the script will still be there.

Other options include invoking it in its own `<iframe>` and carefully invoking it from the main page, and then removing the iframe - this only serves as simple way to remove all of the exported functions, etc, but will not undo any other side effects. To understand how to do that, you'll need to understand fully what the script is doing - hopefully they have documentation to describe how you can achieve what you are after (or perhaps you can clarify your question further).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed guidance . I am actually using GWT Material and using its MaterialTable , Now may material Table is working all fne, But I am also uding PDFTron and for that using this ScriptInjector  ( Added that code in my question also). After adding this script with ScriptInjector, Now when i again open my MaterialTable it gives  error "Material Table is not a function"..  I asked about this from Material people , but no luck . So i can think of just to remove this script somehow before opening my materialTable again

Comment: My best guess is that both GMD and PDFTron bring in their own jQuery, and that when the second jQuery loads it breaks the first jQuery. Try your code again without loading jquery 1.7.2, since GMD already has brought a copy of jQuery into the app.

Comment: aahh , THANK YOU very much , I just removed this and all is good :)